# How can I print a list (employee type) using Iterator?

Tags: java, iterator

**Employee class:**

```
public class Employee {

    int empid;
    String name;
    int age;

    public Employee(int empid,String name,int age)
    {
        this.empid=empid;
        this.name=name;
        this.age=age;
    }
    public int getEmpid() {
        return empid;
    }
    public void setEmpid(int empid) {
        this.empid = empid;
    }
    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setname(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }
    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    } 
}
```

**Comparator class:**

```
public class Employee_comparator implements Comparator<Employee> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Employee object1, Employee object2) {
        return object1.getname().compareTo(object2.getname());
    }
}
```

**Main class:**

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

public class Employee_Main {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Employee> list=new ArrayList<Employee>();

        list.add(new Employee(33186,"varun",23));
        list.add(new Employee(33187,"deepak",23));
        list.add(new Employee(33188,"apple",23));
        list.add(new Employee(33189,"rohan",23));

        Collections.sort(list,new Employee_comparator());

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++) {

            System.out.print("age:"+list.get(i).getAge());
            System.out.print("empid:"+list.get(i).getEmpid());
            System.out.println("name:"+list.get(i).getname());
        }

        Iterator<Employee> itr=list.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(itr.next());
        }
    }
}
```

When I try printing by using get methods, it is working fine. But when, I try to print the elements of the list using `Iterator`, it's giving the following output:

```
new_.Employee@28122812new_.Employee@280d280dnew_.Employee@28172817new_.Employee@28082808
```

Comment: Have you found a solution in the answers? You can accept one!

Answer (score 11):

You can implement a method `toString()` in the class `Employee`:

```
public String toString(){
    return "Name: "+ this.name
       + ". Age:"+ this.age
       + ". Id:"+ this.empId; 
} //example
```

This way, when you do:

`System.out.println(itr.next());`

it will print the `name`, the `age` and the `id` of the employee

Comment: System.out.println(itr.next().toString()); in that case

Comment: explicit `toString()` call not needed, it will call the overriden `toString()` anyway.

Answer (score 5):

Because `itr.next()` has return Object of the class `Employee` that you have sotre in it.
try

```
    Iterator<Employee> itr=list.iterator();

    while(itr.hasNext())
    {
        Employee employee = itr.next();

        System.out.print("age:"+employee.getAge());
        System.out.print("empid:"+employee.getEmpid());
        System.out.println("name:"+employee.getname());
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

You are printing the Employee class object and not its values,

Try :

```
Iterator<Employee> itr=list.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext())
{
    //System.out.println(itr.next());
    System.out.println(itr.next().getEmpid());
}
```

<strike>Between, use enhanced for loop, it is faster than iterator.</strike>

**EDIT:**

Enhanced for loop is more readable than Iterator. Whereas, Iterator gives you option of removing values using iterator.remove() method. for loop throws ConcurrentModificationException if you try to update list during loop.

Comment: is it really faster? prove it

Comment: @dantuch: ahh, I meant better readability over Iterator. Anyways enhanced for loop could be written in lesser lines (or characters), in that way it is faster (to type) at least :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do the same in Java 8 using below code

`Iterator<Employee> employees = list.iterator();
 employees.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);`

or simply,

`list.iterator.forEachRemaining(System.out::println);`

Answer (score 2):

Override the `toString` method so that you can get the `Employee` details even if its `toString` method is called.

```
public void toString(){
 return "Employee Id: "+empid+" Name: "+name+" Age: "+age;
}
```

Now when you call `itr.next()` your `Employee` class `toString` method is called and now it will return the `String` that you have created in the overriden `toString` method.

Answer (score 1):

your itr.next() contains employee object and it will print toString() method. Since you have not override to String method you get this. You could override to String method as you want and

```
System.out.println(itr.next());
```

will print what is it in toString() method.

This will be in your Employee class

```
 @Override
public String toString() {
    return "Employee [empid=" + empid + ", name=" + name + ", age=" + age + "]";
}
```

Comment: System.out.println(itr.next().toString()); in that case

Comment: @Ankit nope, it will call the overriden `toString()` anyway

Answer (score 0):

You should add a Employee method to your class:

```
public void printEmploee()
{
  System.out.printf("ID:%s \nName: %s \nAge: %s \n",
  this.id, this.name, this.age);
}
```

Then use the Iterator:

```
Iterator<Employee> itr = list.iterator();
while (itr.hasNext()) {
itr.next().printEmploee();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static void filter(List c) {
        int i=0;
        for (Iterator<String> it = c.iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            if (it.next() != null)
                System.out.println(c.get(i));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Use toString method() ,it will be printed

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).